# vs code icon not showing in activities bar Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: 18.10, visual-studio-code

this is my screen shot vs code is running but in left side bar its not showing

[image]

how to fix this issue?  and i download from [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/) (official page)
and my

> vs code version 1.29

after update also i have same issue

Comment: I can reproduce it here.  But if you add to favorite the orange dot still works.

Comment: added already its not showing :(   in menu right cick add to fav i did this

Comment: after restart pc  its work but should add favorite